# Ran out of Ram while training LSTM

Tags: python, memory, pytorch, lstm, torch

I am kind of a beginner in RNNs, so I coded a LSTM architecture using Pytorch, but I always run out of RAM whenever I am in the 3rd epoch. I am already using a DataLoader and I tried to detach the gradient from the input tensor but it doesn't solve the problem out.

This is my training loop

```
writer = SummaryWriter()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='mean', ignore_index = 0)
optimizer = optim.Adam(lstm.parameters(), lr = 1e-5)
gradient_clip = clip_grad_norm_(lstm.parameters(), max_norm = 5)

num_epochs = 20
epoch_loss = -1.0
loss = - 1

t = trange(num_epochs, desc= "Epoch loss",  leave=True)

for epoch in t:
    trainLoader = iter(DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = batch_size))

    tt = trange(len(trainLoader)-1,  desc= "Batch loss",  leave=True)

    for i in tt:

        text, embedding = next(trainLoader)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize

        y = lstm.forward(embedding.transpose(1,0))

        labels = text.transpose(0,1)[1:].transpose(0,1).flatten()

        loss = criterion(y.reshape(-1, y.shape[-1]), labels)


        tt.set_description("Batch loss : %.4f" % loss)

        tt.refresh()

        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

        optimizer.step()

        epoch_loss += loss


    epoch_loss = epoch_loss / (len(trainLoader) - 1)

    # Saving model
    save_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y-%H:%M:%S")
    PATH = './save/lstm_model_'+save_date
    torch.save(lstm, PATH)

    # Updating progression bar

    t.set_description("Epoch loss : %.4f" % epoch_loss)

    t.refresh()

    # Plotting gradients histograms in Tensorboard

    writer.add_scalar('Text_generation_Loss/train', epoch_loss, epoch)

    for tag, parm in lstm.named_parameters():

        with torch.no_grad():

            writer.add_histogram(tag, parm.grad.data.cpu().numpy(), epoch)


    writer.flush()

print('Finished Training')

writer.close()
```

And this is the LSTM class that I built:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_size : int, hidden_size : int):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_size = in_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.W_fi = nn.Linear(in_size,hidden_size)
        self.W_fh = nn.Linear(hidden_size,hidden_size, bias=False)
        self.W_ii = nn.Linear(in_size,hidden_size)
        self.W_ih = nn.Linear(hidden_size,hidden_size, bias=False)
        self.W_Ci = nn.Linear(in_size,hidden_size)
        self.W_Ch = nn.Linear(hidden_size,hidden_size, bias=False)
        self.W_oi = nn.Linear(in_size,hidden_size)
        self.W_oh = nn.Linear(hidden_size,hidden_size, bias=False)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()

    def one_step(self, x, h, C):
        f_t = self.sigmoid(self.W_fi(x) + self.W_fh(h))
        i_t = self.sigmoid(self.W_ii(x) + self.W_ih(h))
        g_t = self.tanh(self.W_Ci(x) + self.W_Ch(h))
        C_t = torch.mul(f_t, C) + torch.mul(i_t, g_t)
        o_t = self.sigmoid(self.W_oi(x) + self.W_oh(h))
        h_t = torch.mul(o_t, self.tanh(C_t))
        return h_t, C_t

    def forward(self, X):
        h_out = []
        h = - torch.ones(X.shape[1], self.hidden_size)
        C = - torch.ones(X.shape[1], self.hidden_size)
        h_t, C_t = self.one_step(X[0], h, C)
        h_out.append(h_t)

        for i in range(1, X.shape[0]  - 1):
            h_t, C_t = self.one_step(X[i], h_t, C_t)
            h_out.append(h_t)
        h_out = torch.cat(h_out)

        return h_out #h_out.reshape(-1,batch_size,num_embeddings)
```

I already searched for a similar case but I wasn't able to find a solution

Comment: Are you asking us to help you with getting more ram?...

Comment: No, I am only asking if there is something wrong I do in Pytorch since I am still a beginner

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it may help somebody, but I solved the problem. I wasn't perhaps clear about the task, but the goal was to make text generation. The first thing I was doing is embed the sentences using torch.nn.embedding that was defined outside my LSTM. The solution was to include it as a layer of my network, since the embedding is not a pretrained one and should be learned too.